# TypeScript: Template Literal Type doesn't exclude spaces

Tags: typescript, string

How to declare a template literal type that that prohibits spaces in between?

This is what i have, but it allows spaces between number and unit.

```
 type Duration =`${number}${'ms' | `s`}`
    
    let a: Duration = "2000 ms" // should not compile due to ' ' 
    let b: Duration = "2s" // ok
    let c: Duration = "2000ms" // ok
```

[>> typescriptlang.org playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgVwE4EMQEsD2A7GBeAAwBIBvbBAWwCMokBfUgcgoGdGYAfGAlgug4MAA2UEDBQAueMjRZceGACIATAAZ1MVopgB6HTBYALTAiEATGNkxiAxpgoR0I4aJhUpiVBhz4lyltp6MJgA1i62HjLe8n7qqlq6%20qHAQA)

Comment: Have you tried ``type Duration<T extends number> = `${T}${'ms' | 's'}` ``? Seems that if you use a generic type the problem disappears.

Comment: I think it is not supported in typescript in a way you expect. However, we can use typescript inference on function arguments. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/w2zkxw)

Comment: This is a known bug in TypeScript :)

Comment: do you have a source/ticket-id?

Comment: You say "permits" but you mean the opposite, right?  Can you change it to "prohibits" or something like it?

Comment: The issue in question is [ms/TS#46109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46109).  Do you want that as an answer to the question?  Or are you mostly looking for a workaround (like a generic helper function, mentioned above).  Let me know (and mention @jcalz in your reply so I'm notified)

Comment: @jcalz In my use case the answer is: it is not possible due to TS#46109, but the workaround is the generic helper function. If you like to answer it this way, go ahead.

Comment: And do you want to allow `"0xabcdefms"` or `"-2.5e+1s"` here?  Or are you really only worried about spaces? (mention @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: It turns out to be quite involved to make a helper function. The one @captain-yossarianfromUkraine presented doesn't work for inputs like `"2000ms"` (two "holes" next to each other cause the first hole to consume just one character).  Perhaps [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WGAY2N) works for you?  If so, let me know and I'll mention the workaround in the answer.  Otherwise I'll just point to ms/TS#46109.  Remember to mention @jcalz to notify me.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Digit = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9;
type Unit = 'ms' | 's';
type ValidDuration = `${Digit}${number | ""}${Unit}` & `${number | ""}${Digit}${Unit}`;

let a: ValidDuration = "1 ms" // error as intended
let b: ValidDuration = "2s" // ok
let c: ValidDuration = "2000ms" // ok

const duration = (value: ValidDuration) => value


const x = duration("1ms"); // okay
const y = duration("20000ms"); // okay
const w = duration("1 ms"); // error as intended
const v = duration(" 1ms"); // error as intended
```

Cf. [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4&ssl=2&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=24#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgczsKBeKAGKAfKBGHKAJkIGZCAWQgVkIDZCB2QgDkIE4BuAKFEigCqAO2RooAcgC2AZ3GFxsnn2gA1AIYAbOABMYAVwBOa4HAD2QsQAMAJAG94SYAF87QvZIBGEA4QBEvl1thZCdLKAAyKBtbN09vPwC7BxC7YOdLHm4NCBQ1AC4odS1dQ2MzC3RfAhlfKAB6OqhvA1MfNWkoOCFgCCFtCG0snKgPAqKdfSMTczFfImlahqhTAGshlABjMc0J0umKqDmMY5r6xtXubg3zaRRtPfKxAAoAN009CG3iybLzAEo0AA+KBvDQfS5XG4oAAeYnuU3KTyqNT+nDOyxWahAkKEtygIDhD3MSKIxxOC1R6NWWJxeIA7oSEcSqlAUWils1WlB2p1ur1+oNrriUC9Gb8hEj8Gz0Zy2h0uj0+gMIUA). This is just a solution to prohibit the unwanted spaces. It illustrates the basic idea, viz. to check whether the substring to be interpreted as a number starts and ends with a digit (and therefore leading and trailing spaces are prohibited). More elaboration is necessary if unnecessary leading zeros should be excluded (That is, prohibit "03ms" but allow "0ms") and if numbers other than natural ones should be allowed (e.g. "5.2ms" or "-7s").